# Как заменить объекты в массиве?

Tags: массивы, объекты, render

Есть объекты такого вида:

```js
objectForScroll = { height: layout.height, offset: layout.y, id: this.props.currentFieldId }
```

Я делаю push в массив arrayOfSizes, когда происходит отрисовка каждого поля на странице. Проблема в том, что запись в массив происходит при каждом ререндеринге, и в теории массив может быть бесконечным.
Мне нужно написать условие, если объект с данным id уже существует в массиве, то переписать его, и если объекта с таким id нет в массиве, то записать его.
Все это нужно для того чтобы в итоге получался одномерный массив, с всегда одинаковом кол-во объектов внутри. То есть чтобы, в массив не происходила запись бесконечно. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое?

```js
let arrayOfSizes = [ 
{ height: 1, offset: 1, id: 1 }, 
{ height: 2, offset: 2, id: 2 },
{ height: 3, offset: 3, id: 3 },
{ height: 4, offset: 4, id: 4 },
{ height: 5, offset: 5, id: 5 }];

let newObject = { height: 15, offset: 15, id: 1 };

let newArrayOfSizes = arrayOfSizes.map(item => item.id === newObject.id? newObject:item);

console.log(newArrayOfSizes);
```

или такой вариант

```js
let arrayOfSizes = [ 
{ height: 1, offset: 1, id: 1 }, 
{ height: 2, offset: 2, id: 2 },
{ height: 3, offset: 3, id: 3 },
{ height: 4, offset: 4, id: 4 },
{ height: 5, offset: 5, id: 5 }];

let newObject = { height: 15, offset: 15, id: 1 };
var oldObject = arrayOfSizes.find(item => item.id === newObject.id);
Object.assign(oldObject, newObject);

console.log(arrayOfSizes);
```

Условия по типу существует или нет пишется просто.

```js
let arrayOfSizes =[ 
    { height: 1, offset: 1, id: 1 }, 
    { height: 2, offset: 2, id: 2 },
    { height: 3, offset: 3, id: 3 },
    { height: 4, offset: 4, id: 4 },
    { height: 5, offset: 5, id: 5 }];

let newObject = { height: 10, offset: 10, id: 10 };

if (arrayOfSizes.find(item => item.id === newObject.id )) {
  //... выбирайте произвольный необходимый для вас вариант
} else {
  arrayOfSizes.push(newObject);
}

console.log(arrayOfSizes);
```

Comment: objectForScroll у меня объект, а не массив. Задача в том, что если в массиве arrayOfSizes нет объекта objectForScroll с таким id, то записать его. А если, объект уже имеется в массиве, то перезаписать его.

Comment: а так понятнее?

Comment: как написать замену? то есть если с таким id уже имеется чтобы его переписывал?

Comment: есть такая загвоздка, массив изначально пустой, только после вышесказанных проверок должен получится массив с объектами. Проверка нужна для того чтобы каждый раз при ререндеринге получался массив с всегда одинаковым кол-во объектов внутри

Comment: Я же написал вам замену. Два варианта запустите и посмотрите каждый. Чтобы получалось всегда одинаковое число элементов то push не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь разобраться. Если что буду спрашивать)

Comment: Первый рендер код отлично отрабатывает, потом при ререндере в первом условии нужно что то менять. Object.assign не подходит так как у меня массив. Можете что то подсказать?

Comment: Тогда через первый вариант. Это имутабельная схема. Вы не меняете а заменяете